# mod_jk with JBoss 5.x Community Server

Tags: jboss5.x, mod-jk

Configuring Apache's mod_jk (used just as a proxy, not as loadbalancer) is supported with JBoss 5.x Community Server?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using mod_jk, mod_cluster is a better option for JBoss. It also has support for sticky session and session replication. Mod_cluster works both with Wildfly/JBoss AS since version 5 and with Tomcat 6+. If you are looking only for mod_jk, JBoss documentation can help. Mod_cluster doc and info: http://modcluster.io